# How to open popup behind main window (HTML,jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, popup

I'm new.
i have a popup code that when user click anywhere in the HTML page, a popup window shows up:

```
(function () {
    document.onclick = function () {

        var sUrl = "http://URL.com";

        if (typeof daily_capping == "undefined") var daily_capping = 10;

        if (typeof capping_minutes == "undefined") var capping_minutes = 60;

        if (document.cookie.indexOf("_popwin=") === -1) {

            var ads2day = document.cookie.split("_popwinDaily=")[1];

            ads2day = typeof ads2day == "undefined" ? 0 : parseInt(ads2day.split(";")[0]);

            if (ads2day < daily_capping) {

                var isMSIE = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ? !0 : !1,
                    _parent = self,
                    sOptions, popunder;

                if (top != self) try {
                    top.document.location.toString() && (_parent = top)
                } catch (err) {}

                sOptions = "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=yes,statusbar=yes,menubar=no,resizable=1,width=" + screen.width.toString() + ",height=" + (screen.height - 20).toString() + ",screenX=0,screenY=0,left=0,top=0", popunder = _parent.window.open(sUrl, "rhpop", sOptions);

                if (popunder) {
                    popunder.blur();
                    if (isMSIE) {
                        window.focus();
                        try {
                            opener.window.focus()
                        } catch (err) {}
                    } else popunder.init = function (e) {
                        with(e)(function () {
                            if (typeof window.mozPaintCount != "undefined" || typeof navigator.webkitGetUserMedia == "function") {
                                var e = window.open("about:blank");
                                e.close()
                            }
                            try {
                                opener.window.focus()
                            } catch (t) {}
                        })()
                    }, popunder.params = {
                        url: sUrl
                    }, popunder.init(popunder)
                }

                var now = new Date,
                    popDaily = (new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), 23, 59, 59)).toGMTString();

                document.cookie = "_popwinDaily=" + (ads2day + 1) + ";expires=" + popDaily + ";path=/";

                var popInterval = new Date;
                popInterval.setTime(popInterval.getTime() + capping_minutes * 60 * 1e3), document.cookie = "_popwin=1;expires=" + popInterval.toGMTString() + ";path=/"

            }
        }
    }
})();
```

but popup is on top. is it possible to make it open behind main page??
is there any lighter popup code for this purpose?
thanks guys

Comment: I think browsers actively try to prevent this sort of thing nowadays. It's considered naughty.

Comment: Popunder ads are a spammy, disgusting abomination. I *hope* there is no way to do this any more.

Comment: I agree with Blazemonger, this is considered bad practice.  Even though it may have a totally legit purpose, most major browsers as well as ad blockers would prevent it.  They may even prevent a pop-up in "front" of everything as well.  Have you considered a DIV set to `display:none;` ?  If the propose is legit, this should suit your needs. You could then put the div "behind" another div.  It probably won't work with "spammy" Javascript however.

Comment: Perhaps post the purpose of making this pop up behind the window, and someone can come up with a better alternative.

Comment: Blazemonger and pekka: any suggestion instead??

Comment: @3dgoo: I just want not to bother users with popup on top. we need ads.

Comment: @sara.ma: Try to embed them in the page somewhere, rather than using a popup.

Comment: That is both deceitful to your end users, and to the advertiser ...  Baaaadd juju ..   I would waive you off the attempt at this point.  You will lose credibility and trust both by advertisers and users both.

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely should not be doing this. Pop up ads are invasive and annoying. Having pop up windows open secretly underneath the window is even more dirty.

If you do not want to bother users do not use any type of pop up window for you ads.

Alternatively you could display your ads inline in the existing page.

Pop up windows like this are most likely going to be blocked by modern browers anyway. They are blocked for the reason that users do not want to see this kind of action, and it can be dangerous.

Do not make hidden pop up ads.

Comment: Im upvoting your answer and deleting mine,  pop ups are annoying enough, but intentionally putting ad under main window is bad, im guessing for a spam porn site